# Is there a difference between $\rm SiO_2/Si$ and $\rm Si/SiO_2$ when describing the substrate of a field-effect transistors?

Tags: terminology, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I've seen in different papers that the substrate of a FET is $\text{SiO}_2/\text{Si}$ or $\text{Si}/\text{SiO}_2$.  Are they describing the same thing or is the order important?

Comment: Define substrate. Are we talking a buried oxide here, or is the SiO2 the gate (so not really substrate)?

Comment: I'm referring to substrate in the organic field-effect transistor context so something like in this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_field-effect_transistor#/media/File:OfetEng.png.

Comment: I guess I’d call it an SiO2/Si back gate, but might be out of touch with organic FET terminology. Check a few recent papers?